# How to ask for question re-opening?

Tags: support, status-completed, review-queues

I was about to ask a question and I found it was already asked by someone else some time ago: [How to compute time-space maps automatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158319/)

Unfortunately, this question has been closed mainly due to poor wording and formatting I guess. I have edited the question to improve it (hopefully) and would like to see it re-open to be answered (hopefully). How to 'force' such re-opening?

Answer (score 6):

Editing a closed question will put it into the Reopen queue for the community to vote to reopen or keep closed.  Your edit has put it into that queue - it now has 1 reopen vote (yours).  It says there are 4 more votes required to reopen the question.

[image]

If you look at the [@PolyGeo's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158319/how-to-compute-time-space-maps-automatically#comment319132_158319) on that question you will see the reason it is considered too broad is because it is focused on two GIS packages (effectively making it two questions.)

> reduce the scope of your question to either QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop. At the moment I suspect it is falling between the cracks of the two sub-communities.

Once is it reduced to one question about one GIS software it will be less broad.

If you feel that you can write a more specific question that is clear and not broad, I think it will be OK for you to ask your own question separately - I would be surprised if the community votes to close yours as a Duplicate of a closed broad question with no answers.

Comment: I use both ArcGIS and QGIS Software, but would consider this to be too broad a question and the OP needs to decide which one to use or ask two questions.

Comment: Exactly, the first step to re-opening is addressing the close reason. My comment on that question was to try and help the asker know the main issue with it in case they were not familiar with the wording of the close reason.